# how to fetch full URL for my webservice in opensource SOAPUI?

Tags: web-services, groovy, soapui

In my teardown script for my test case, I need to capture the URL which is being used and report it using log.info. I am unable to find the correct property to achieve this.

I am using following script as of now.

```
def failedTestCases = 0
def successTestCases = 0
def failedTestSteps = 0
def successTestSteps = 0
def failedAssertions = 0
def successAssertions = 0

def env = request.url
File file = new File("C:/tmp/testcase_results.txt")
file.text=''
runner.results.each { testCaseResult ->
    def caseName = testCaseResult.testCase.name
        def caseStatus = testCaseResult.status.toString()
        if(caseStatus == 'FAILED'){
             failedTestCases ++
             file << "Test Case: $caseName" + " has failed \n \n"
             file << "env-" + env
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to know the test step name, which you should be able to get dynamically. Then you can get the URL like this:

```
def testStepName = testCaseResult.testCase.testStep.name
def testStep = context.testCase.getTestStepByName(testStepName)
def wsdlUrl = testStep.getPropertyValue('Endpoint')
log.info wsdlUrl
```

It is a standard property for every WsdlTestStep.